# DXB - Arriving and departing from Terminal 3

Tags: dubai, emirates, dxb

My flight arrives at DXB in Terminal 3 (EK649) and departs also from Terminal 3 (EK261). I don't have the arrival or departure gate numbers but both of them are in Terminal 3. I tried looking at the DXB map but I'm not quite sure I understand how to get from the arrivals to the departures in Terminal 3?

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves right, you just get off the plane and follow the signs to "Connections" and/or directly to your departure gate. You will probably have to go through security again and you may have to take the train between "A" and "B & C".

If you don't know the gate just look it up at the nearest info display.

Do NOT go to anything saying "Exit" or "Baggage Claim".

Here are some videos:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAZx9qlYI_s,
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4K8IAs5KMc

From Emirates websites https://www.emirates.com/us/english/before-you-fly/dubai-international-airport/transferring-between-terminals/

> It’s easy to connect to another Emirates flight in Dubai. All our flights arrive and depart from Emirates Terminal 3 at Dubai International airport. When you arrive, simply follow the signs to Connections and make your way to the gate for your next Emirates flight.

Comment: I assume it's still the case that DXB has you go through security when making a connection, so it's not quite just going to the gate, but agreed that you just follow the signs for connecting flights and you'll end up in the right place.